# Flutter: Reset state of child BLOC depending of state of parent BLOC

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

I need to reset state of child BLOC when state of parent BLOC is changed. Let's say I have an image which is managed by `ChildBloc` which have a method for image scaling (so `ChildBloc.state` has a `scale` property).

When user scales image the current `scale` is saved in `ChildBloc` state and persistent. When user goes out from the page and returned back the scale must be restored.

When user changes image (let's say select new item in images list and of couuse state of `ParentBloc` is changed then state of `ChildBloc` must be set to initial and any persistence must be cleared.

Any idea how do I need to link states of those BLOCs? Is it a good idea to keep state of `ChildBloc` as part of state of `ParentBloc`?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the best state management approach is without knowing what the application does and how it works.

Anyway, in your case you have at least 2 options:

1. **Unify the Parent and Child states**. This approach would solve your problem as you have all the state in a single bloc. But it could be a really big change (again, depends on how your `ChildBloc` is structured)
2. **Refer to ChildBloc inside a ParentBloc event**. I guess that when the user changes image in the `ParentBloc` you throw an event. You could refer to che `ChildBloc` and throw a `resetState` event.
   Something like: `context.read<ChildBloc>().resetState(ResetStateEvent(...));`. You need the BuildContext to do this, but you can pass it in the `ParentBloc` event.